# Get Screen Position From World Position

Tags: c, directx, directx-9

I want to get Screen Position from World Position in DirectX.

I can get my ball's world position. But I can't know how can I convert it to screen position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a view/eye transform V (the one that "places" your "camera") and a projection transform P.

Clip space coordinates are reached by

```
clip_position = P * V * world_space_position
```

From clip space you reach NDC space by dividing the clip space coordinates by the 4th clip space coordinate w, i.e.

```
ndc_x = clip_x / clip_w
ndc_y = clip_y / clip_w
ndc_z = clip_z / clip_w
ndc_w = clip_w / clip_w = 1
```

The viewport XY coordinates are then reached by mapping the range [-1,1] to the viewport dimensions. The difference between OpenGL and DirectX is, that in OpenGL the depth range [-1,1] is mapped to [0, DEPTH_BUFFER_RESOLUTION], while in DirectX it's the depth range [0, 1] that maps to the depth buffer value range.

Comment: view/eye transform means D3DTS_VIEW?

Comment: D3DXMATRIX matProj,matView;
m_pd3dDevice->GetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW,&matView);
m_pd3dDevice->GetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION,&matProj);
D3DXMatrixMultiply(&matProj,&matProj,&matView);
D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&pos,&pos,&matProj);

But pos.z is smaller than -1 not in the range [-1,1]

Comment: @bTagTiger: You can safely ignore the Z position, if you're interested in only the screen position.

Comment: Could you explain about this more , please.

Comment: My Screen Width is 1024, and Height is 768. 
After I get pos, How can I convert this x,y( [-1,1] ) to screen pos( [1024,768])

Comment: @bTagTiger: Unh, this is the most simple form of linear equation. If you can't solve such a simple thing, then I think 3D programming is not for you. Well, here it goes: `a = (b-1)/2 * {1024, 768}`. But seriously, if a simple affine equation exceeds your skills, then you'd better get your math straigt, before diving in 3D programming, as 3D programming is just math, math, math. And for OpenGL and Direct3D of particular interest are such linear, affine equations.

Comment: Well, Not you are right.
I get value pos.y ,-1.5 not -1. You said All values are in [-1,1].
I can't know what is wrong. So I want to know how can I transform this position!!!

Comment: Also Sometimes I get pos.x -30.5

Comment: @bTagTiger: My best guess is, that your VIEW matrix is not just world to eye space transform, but some local transform applied as well. Please post your code as an update to your question.

Comment: I used D3DXVec3Project function to get screen position.

Comment: But the y value is always bigger than 398.

Comment: @bTagTiger: Then you do something seriously wrong. Please post your code, otherwise we can only guess.