# Getting object position in 2D relatively to perspective camera position and direction

Tags: 3d, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

I use `SpriteBatch` to draw some post effect. There are 3D object and perspective camera which moves and rotates. In case if the object becomes visible, I have to get its 2D coordinates depending on the center of screen.

[image]

So, I need to convert 3D object position in 2D coordinates relative to position and direction of perspective camera. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201260/get-screen-position-from-world-position

Comment: @Martin Wickman, thanks for your answer, but I was finding a solution relative to LibGDX and I have already found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution of problem. `Camera` class has `project()` function. So, I pass `Vector3` there and get position on the screen.

```
Vector3 objectPosition = new Vector3(x,y,z); // position of object somewhere in 3D space
camera.project(objectPosition);
//do something with objectPosition vector.
```

Hope it helps someone else.